# How can I make a single WCF method ConcurrencyMode.Multiple when service is ConcurencyMode.Single

Tags: c#, wcf, multithreading

I have a service which is defined as ConcurrencyMode.Single:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyService : IMyService
```

This service provides a method to tell the client what it's currently working on:

```
    [OperationContract]
    string GetCurrentTaskDescription();
```

Is there a way to make this particular method allowable while another long-running task is running where all other methods still follow the single-threaded concurrency model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make methods have an instance context mode.

If you really need a single threaded set of calls and one multithreaded set of calls you will need to create a new service contract for this call.

Comment: or make the whole service multi-threaded and synchronize all other methods manually

Comment: Thats a good point.  I guess the onus is on the developer to get that right though.